# AngularJS app becoming slow on IE 8

Tags: performance, angularjs

I have a AngularJS application that makes use of web services to load the content and render the view. I've checked the performance of application on Chrome and it is running fast enough. However on IE 8, I'm facing huge performance issues.

Noticed the memory usage for Internet Explorer. Found that it was around 200MB. If I opened multiple instances of the application in separate tabs, the memory usage kept on doubling with each instance. This is slowing down the response time and in the effect the whole PC performance. No such issues are there on Chrome.

I feel that it is because of the data that is present in the model for the application. So with each tab on IE, the model data is doubled and the RAM usage also increases. However, this problem doesn't occur for me in Chrome.

Please suggest some performance optimization techniques that I can use.

Comment: Note that M$ is dropping support for WinXP and its IE8 this April. Also, the Angular guys are dropping the IE8 support in the next version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to avoid the use of "ng-repeat" for a large list rendering. Or, you can use the infinite scrolling for the same.

Comment: Even infinite scrolling goes with ng-repeat itself right? So how can I avoid ng-repeat for large lists?

Comment: If you render small list then ng-repeat takes less time. So, render small small part of the list using infinite scroll.